C# WPF Setting padding on a grid in an more ergonomic way
I'm new to WPF and am a bit confused by the purposes of setters. For example, in a Grid, I would intuitively like to code this:
    <Grid Padding="5,5,5,5">
    ...

But I can't. I have to do this instead:
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
    ...

This seems a strangely inefficient and roundabout way to specify this. Some properties I can set by simply expressing them, and for others I need to use a property setter. What is the underlying reason for this, and is there a way to avoid this roundabout mechanism?

You are confusing things. A DataGrid is not a Grid. A Grid does not have a Padding property. <Style TargetType="Border"> in a Grid's Resources affects all child elements of the Grid that are of type Border.

Apologies, I meant Grid. Am using a DataGrid elsewhere. I will correct the question.

A Grid does still not have a Padding property. What is your question?

Ah, so I'm collectively setting all the Padding properties of all the Border elements contained within the Grid?

Yes. The live visual tree is the best thing to look through to understand what's really going on. WPF likes to hide to many UI Elements in my opinion.

Styles and templates (WPF .NET)
